# Google Play services version issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a problem - i'm using Google Maps v2 in my application. To use it i obvious added Google Play services lib to my project.

Everything is working great on my device but crash on others with older Android, for example, my app work on 4.3 but don't work on 4.0.3.

I have figured out the problem - on these devices Google Play services are not last version. 
In Android SDK Tools i have Google Play services revision 13. When i have installed update of Google Play services my application works fine.

So what the best way to solve this problem? 
May be i need to use some older methods to get map from MapFragment?
Here's my code.

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends MapFragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public void init() {
        mMap = getMap(); <----------- NPE when launched on older Android devices
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        init();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

In order to let `Google Map API V2` to work on older devices you have to use the `SupportMapFragment` object instead of `MapFragment` object. So thats what you have to extend.

You have to use the `SupportFragmentManager` to get it's instance instead of the usually used `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i looking for. And problem not in SupportMapFragment vs MapFrament.

My application will work on Android 4+

The problem is that on different Android starting from 4+ Google Play Services are different version.

And somehow my application compiled to use latest GooglePlay services.

Comment: Then check this blog post: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435 and verify that you have committed step 10 and added the new needed mata-data tag in your Manifest file.

Comment: Didn't yet try but it's sounds promising. Thank you Emil.